# Circle border shape for table cell with responsive height

Tags: html, css, border, geometry, radial-gradients

[image: Border style]

Hello guys!
How will you do this kind of border without image (look at the image at the top, blue piece of block), just css. The height is flexible. Any suggestion? IE10 support :)

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is what you want, but maybe something like this?

UPDATE: sorry, but I cannot add the link, note can I embed the fiddle as I'm on a mobile and the editor will not let me do either...

> jsfiddle.net/hXMLF/1229/

Comment: I add an image, at the top (blue piece of block) how the right side border should look. Can you see it?